# Compile multiple node.js files into one

Tags: node.js, gulp, webtask

I am writing code for webtask.io and it seems as if I can only upload one file to run.  I would like to organize my code into multiple files with different modules but then have them be compiled into one for upload.  I have tried `gulp` with `gulp-concat` but this just concatenates the files without preserving any execution logic.  I would assume there is a simple way to do this.

Comment: give webpack a try

Comment: What you're looking for is a bundler.  There are several.  webpack seems to be the one I see referred to the most here on stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Webpack works well, especially with the `webpack-node-externals'` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `--bundle` argument.

```
$ wt create index.js --bundle
```